# How to create new instance of a class by passing Object[] instead of parameter list with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

Do you have any clue about how to write such method?

```
public abstract class AbstractClass{}

public class TrialClass extends AbstractClass{
    public TrialClass(final String a, final String b){}
    public TrialClass(final String a, final String b, final String c){}
}

public class getNewInstance(final Class<? extends AbstractClass> clazz, Object... constructorParameters){
    //???
}

TrialClass trialClass = getNewInstance(TrialClass.class, "A", "B");
```

Comment: You have to search the array of constructors for the constructor whose parameters match the arguments.

Comment: Where does `AbstractClass` come into this? Why is it needed?

Comment: And your method signature should be something like `public <T extends AbstractClass> T getNewInstance(final Class<T> clazz, Object... cs);`

Comment: I need AbstractClass becasue this method will be a generic instance creator for all AbstractClass extenders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Class` method contains a `getConstructor` method that takes an array of `Class` as a parameter, corresponding to the constructor arguments. You have to build this array from your parameter array.

Something like that:

```
public <T> T getNewInstance(final Class<T> clazz, Object... constructorParameters) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException{
    Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[constructorParameters.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < constructorParameters.length; i++) {
        parameterTypes[i] = constructorParameters[i].getClass();
    }

    Constructor<T> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(parameterTypes);
    return constructor.newInstance(constructorParameters);
}
```

Edit: as Codebender said, this doesn't work when a subtype is passed as the argument.

Comment: tha part that finds the constructor is correct, but passing arguments to create newInstance have some problems. If we call this method like:
getNewInstance(TrialClass.class, "A", "B");

constructorParameters will be an Object array containing "A" and "B". So we are trying to pass Object array instead of String,String parameters. This code will probably throw IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: constructor.newInstance(constructorParameters[0], constructorParameters[1]) would work for that example.

Comment: @PRowLeR no, `newInstance` expects an Object array, so this is not a problem. However, Codebender is right, you have to use instance of the exact types expected by the constructor (this should be OK with Strings)

Answer (score 3):

Probably more flexible approach is to check all the constructors and find the compatible one like this:

```
public static <T> T getNewInstance(final Class<T> clazz, Object... constructorParameters) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Constructor<?> candidate = null;
    for(Constructor<?> constructor : clazz.getConstructors()) {
        if(Modifier.isPublic(constructor.getModifiers()) && isConstructorCompatible(constructor, constructorParameters)) {
            if(candidate == null)
                candidate = constructor;
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Several constructors found which are compatible with given arguments");
        }
    }
    if(candidate == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No constructor found which is compatible with given arguments");
    return (T) candidate.newInstance(constructorParameters);
}

private static boolean isConstructorCompatible(Constructor<?> constructor, Object[] constructorParameters) {
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = constructor.getParameterTypes();
    if(parameterTypes.length != constructorParameters.length)
        return false;
    for(int i=0; i<parameterTypes.length; i++)
        if(!isParameterCompatible(parameterTypes[i], constructorParameters[i]))
            return false;
    return true;
}

private static boolean isParameterCompatible(Class<?> type, Object parameter) {
    if(parameter == null)
        return !type.isPrimitive();
    if(type.isInstance(parameter))
        return true;
    if(type.isPrimitive()) {
        if (type == int.class && parameter instanceof Integer
                || type == char.class && parameter instanceof Character
                || type == byte.class && parameter instanceof Byte
                || type == short.class && parameter instanceof Short
                || type == long.class && parameter instanceof Long
                || type == float.class && parameter instanceof Float
                || type == double.class && parameter instanceof Double
                || type == boolean.class && parameter instanceof Boolean)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

There are still open issues though like varargs-constructors. Also ambiguity cases will not be resolved like it's done by javac (for example, if you have `MyObj(Object)` and `MyObj(String)` constructor, you will not be able to use the latter one are both match).